# Failed to init entropy source hwrng

Tags: hardware

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1679010

seeing this log:

```
Failed to init entropy source hwrng
```

Does Intel or AMD CPU contain a hwrng device? or it need extra chip/card/device?

Answer (score 0):

No, a CPU typically does not contain a hwrng *device*. Instead, modern x86 CPUs with hardware RNG capabilities typically have a *RDRAND instruction*. It was introduced by Intel in the Ivy Bridge generation (in 2012) and AMD copied it in 2015.

A hwrng device is typically a feature of the system chipset, to provide a hardware RNG even if a processor that doesn't have the RDRAND instruction is installed, or of a security module or cryptographic accelerator card that provides a hardware RNG as an adjunct to their main functionality. There are also dedicated hardware RNG devices, like the [LavaCan](https://www.lavarand.org/what/can-details.html) of the [LavaRNG project](http://www.lavarnd.org/).

Since RDRAND is now ubiquitous in modern x86 CPUs, the chipset designers might as well start omitting the hwrng device in new chipsets to simplify their designs.

Comment: so the message 'Failed to init entropy source hwrng' means there is no hwrng device?

Comment: Either that, or if there was a hwrng device, then it did not work as expected. Is there a /dev/hwrng device node or not?